# Whether preserving inner products follows from preserving intrinsic distances

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces

I know that if a map *F* between two surfaces preserves inner products of tangent vectors and is 1-1 and onto, then it must preserve intrinsic distances, but I’m not sure whether the inverse is true. Namely, is it true that any map *F* between two surfaces that is 1-1, onto, and preserves intrinsic distances will automatically preserve inner products of tangent vectors?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $$F : (S, g) \to (S', g')$$ is a *metric isometry* (homeomorphism that preserves the distance respective functions $d_g, d_{g'}$ of $g, g'$, that is, that satisfies $d_g = F^* d_{g'}$). Then, yes, $F$ is actually a (Riemannian) isometry, i.e., $F^* g' = g$.

To do this, it's certainly enough to give an explicit formula for $g$ in terms of $d_g$ (or even just $g(Z, Z)$, since we can recover $g$ by the Polarization Formula).

**Hint** Compare $g$ with the Euclidean metric in normal coordinates to establish that for any $p$ and $\epsilon > 0$ there is a constant $C > 0$ for which the comparison
$$(1 - C|t|) |t X - t Y|_g \leq d_g(\exp t X, \exp t Y) \leq (1 + C|t|)|t X - t Y|_g$$ holds when $|t| \leq 1$ for all $X, Y \in B_{\epsilon}(p)$.
Conclude that $$|X - Y|_g^2 = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{d_g(\exp tX, \exp tY)^2}{t^2} .$$

For a more detailed hint, see the erratum for p. 112, Problem 6-2 in the [errata to Lee's *Riemannian Manifolds*](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/Riemannian/errata.pdf).

Comment: I've read the hint in the errata you mentioned, and it's of great help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: However, the hint says the fact that metric isometries preserve geodesics needs to be proved first. I'm really new to this field and my understanding is a little bit messed up, but how exactly is this proved? Isn't it necessary to use the property of inner products preserving in proving this fact?

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you've found it helpful. That question perhaps merits a question of its own, but: Geodesics can be defined in an invariant way in terms of the metric, namely, they are the solutions $\gamma(t)$ to the differential equation $\nabla^g_{\gamma'} \gamma' = 0$, so since the isometry maps one metric to the other, it maps the geodesics of the first to those of the second.

Comment: If you prefer something more concrete, for any coordinate chart $(U, \phi)$ on $S'$, $(F^{-1}(U), \phi \circ F)$ is a coordinate chart on $S$. Then, writing the geodesic equations in the two coordinate charts shows that if $\gamma(t)$ is a geodesic of $g$ in $F^{-1}(U)$, then $(F \circ \gamma)(t)$ is a geodesic of $g'$ in $U$.

Comment: I see. It's indeed true that if _F_ preserves the metric tensor, then the geodesics would be preserved. However, the thing here is that we have only required _F_ to preserve distances, not the metric tensor. The hint in the errata seems to say that in order to prove that such _F_ would indeed preserve the metric tensor, we need to first prove that it will preserve geodesics. How can this be done? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah right, I'd nearly forgotten what the question was when I came back to read your comments. The key fact you need here is that geodesics are characterized by the property that they are (locally) distance-minimizing curves.

Comment: That's where I stuck. As I understand it, geodesics locally minimize length, so that its arclength is just the distance between its two endpoints. So I figured to prove geodesics are preserved, it is needed to show that its arclength would stay the same. Then, as the distance is preserved, geodesics would be brought to geodesics, at least up to reparameterization. But the arclength of a curve is defined using the metric tensor, which is the very thing we are trying to show is preserved here.

Comment: So I wonder if it's possible to define arclengths using distances instead of inner products, so it would be preserved automatically as the distance function is preserved. But as of now I have no idea how to actually do it.

Comment: Well, by definition, the distance function $d(x, y)$ induced by a metric is $d(x, y) = \operatorname{inf} \{L(\gamma) : \textrm{$\gamma$ is a curve with endpoints $x, y$}\}$.

Comment: Yeah I know this, and _L(γ)_ is then defined by integrating _g(γ'(t), γ'(t))_, but this is the problem. _F_ right now only preserves the distance function, and that's only the greatest lower bound of arclengths, so it does not necessarily need to preserve all arclengths in order to preserve the infima. To prove geodesics are preserved, however, my current thought is just to prove that its arclength is preserved, which would then mean that it's still a length-minimizing curve, but as said, it seems not necessary for _F_ to preserve the arclengths in order to preserve the distance function.

Comment: If _F_ preserves the inner products, then as _L(γ)_ is defined by integrating _g(γ'(t), γ'(t))_, _L(γ)_ would indeed be preserved, but that's not the case here as we have only required _F_ to preserve the distance function.

Comment: Since we're interested in ensuring the preservation of a local property, we may as well work locally in some chart where the behavior of geodesics is especially nice, e.g., in a geodesic ball centered around one end of a given geodesic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [because](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) $4a\cdot b=(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2$ or, in the complex case, $4a\cdot b=\sum_{n=0}^3 i^{-n}\Vert a+i^n b\Vert^2$.