# Does a map that preserves distance imply isometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry

It feels intuitive for this to be true. Let us say I have a chart from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to some section of a manifold in $\mathbb{R^3}$. If the distance in $\mathbb{R^2}$ between two points is equal to the shortest distance (locally, the geodesic) on the manifold in $\mathbb{R^3}$, does this imply the map is an isometry?

Comment: This is the very definition of isometry, no? A bijection of metric spaces that preserves distance.

Comment: The definition I have is preserves 1st fundamental form $I(x) = |x|^2$ for x in $T_pS$, which implies angle preserving etc.. I guess lengths by extension? But then we need to define shortest length via geodesics, and its not obvious to me from the first fundamental form how to conclude that.

Comment: Perhaps this answers your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3012525/whether-preserving-inner-products-follows-from-preserving-intrinsic-distances

Comment: This is a very special case of the [Meyers-Steenrod theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%E2%80%93Steenrod_theorem), whose proof you can find for instance in Petersen's book "Riemannian Geometry."